# Returning object with decimal from interop

Tags: c#, com, ms-access-2007, com-interop

I have made a com interop object in c# like this:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
public OrderStateModel[] GetOrders(int count, int offset);
```

I call it from MS Access and it shows great potential but I've given up on marshaling the decimals.

```
[Guid("6A6A7BF5-867D-47F3-B28A-10B74511A72D")]
public interface IOrderStateModel
{
   ...

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
    Decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [return :MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
    Decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}
```

I've scoured the web for solutions but I really can't get my head around the type juggling and what it really implies in practice. I've dabbled with CurrencyWrapper as well. In the returned object the decimals end up as huge numbers.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: .NET's Decimal would be translated into a VARIANT of type VT_DECIMAL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is kind of a special COM beast. Not sure Access supports this, as not all COM clients do. You may have to pass a string instead (or an Int64 that you always divide/multiply by 1000 by convention - for example).

Comment: Highly unsatisfying but I went with the string option as per your suggestion.